# VideoJS - Disable Screen for Audio

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video.js

I need VideoJS for a project and everything is working, however if I used the audio-tag I got a black screen for videos.

I tried to minimize the screen with.

```
<audio data-setup="{}" class="vjs-tech" id="vjs_video_3_html5_api" height="0px"src="/fileadmin/content/media/16_Allgemeine_Schriften/02_Zeitungen_Zeitschriften/Haller_Kreisblatt/SoundHelix-Song-1__1_.mp3">
```

But it didn't working for me.

Has anyone a hint or idea for me ?